# HttpClients.createDefault error?

Tags: java, request, httpclient, invocationtargetexception

i created a RestUtils library which uses org.apache.httpclient and this is what happens:

i have this fragment of code inside these library:

```
    ...
    // Make the request
    this.httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    this.method.setHeaders(headerArray);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = this.httpClient.execute(this.method);
    HttpRestResponse response = new HttpRestResponse();
    ...
```

Well happens that first line (createDefault method) works ok when i call this method from "strap" project, but when i call it from "social" project, it fails at these line. This is not throwing any error, but debugging i found this exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

What could be the reason for createDefault() method fails depending where i call from? Regards

Edit:
I found that exception because inside method "invokeMethod()" (some internal method of createDefault()) it gets into this catch:

```
catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
  testResult.setThrowable(ite.getCause());
  testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
}
```

As i said, this doesn't have e.printStackTrace() and i can't add it because i have it as depndency and i am not able to edit it

However, i have a catch where i call createDefaults method and it doesn't print stacktrace neither

```
    try {
        ...
        // Make the request
        this.httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is rarely the _cause_. It usually wraps another exception and you should be able to see it in the rest of the stack trace. Post that here.

Comment: It doesn't print the stack trace because the error is caught by the invoker method called inside createDefault and it hasn't got the line e.printStacktrace() (and i can't modify it because i have it as dependency)    
catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
      testResult.setThrowable(ite.getCause());
      testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
    }

Comment: Then when you step your code, add the following expression in your "watch" window: `ex.printStackTrace()`. That should trigger a dump of the stacktrace to the console.

Comment: What is `testResult`? Do you have access to that? Don't post code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: testResult is a internal class from some method called by HttpClients.creatDefault(). No, i have not access to it

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was due to forgetting to include the library commons-logging-1.2.jar